# I was running a project in Python, whenever I run the project on my Macbook it shows black screen and whenever I run it on Window PC it runs perfectly

Tags: python, windows, macos, openweathermap

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.resizable(0, 0)

root.title("Weather App")

city_value = StringVar()


def time_format_for_location(utc_with_tz):
    local_time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(utc_with_tz)
    return local_time.time()


city_value = StringVar()


def showweather():
    api_key = "b2e73c0a622422f7174769f04dc15c94"
    city_name = city_value.get()
    weather_url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city_name + '&appid=' + api_key
    response = requests.get(weather_url)
    weather_info = response.json()
    tfield.delete("1.0", "end")

    if weather_info['cod'] == 200:
        kelvin = 273

        temp = int(weather_info['main']['temp'] - kelvin)
        feels_like_temp = int(weather_info['main']['feels_like'] - kelvin)
        pressure = weather_info['main']['pressure']
        humidity = weather_info['main']['humidity']
        wind_speed = weather_info['wind']['speed'] * 3.6
        sunrise = weather_info['sys']['sunrise']
        sunset = weather_info['sys']['sunset']
        timezone = weather_info['timezone']
        cloudy = weather_info['clouds']['all']
        description = weather_info['weather'][0]['description']

        sunrise_time = time_format_for_location(sunrise + timezone)
        sunset_time = time_format_for_location(sunset + timezone)
        weather = f"\nWeather of: {city_name}\nTemperature (Celsius): {temp}°\nFeels like in (Celsius): " \
                  f"{feels_like_temp}°\nPressure: {pressure} hPa\nHumidity: " \
                  f"{humidity}%\nSunrise at {sunrise_time} and Sunset at {sunset_time}\nCloud: " \
                  f"{cloudy}%\nInfo: {description}"
    else:
        weather = f"\n\tWeather for '{city_name}' not found!\n\tKindly Enter valid City Name !!"

    tfield.insert(INSERT, weather)
    city_head = Label(root, text='Enter City Name', font='Arial 12 bold').pack(pady=10)

    inp_city = Entry(root, textvariable=city_value, width=24, font='Arial 14 bold').pack()

    Button(root, command=showWeather, text="Check Weather", font="Arial 10", bg='lightblue', fg='black',
           activebackground="teal", padx=5, pady=5).pack(pady=20)


weather_now = Label(root, text="The Weather is:", font='arial 12 bold').pack(pady=10)

tfield = Text(root, width=46, height=10)
tfield.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

What could be leading to tkinter showing up with the black screen?

I have tried reinstalling python 3.7 and changed to python 3.8 both with no luck. At the time I was trying to get the pyinstaller tool to work on making the app an executable which required making some changes to the packages in pyinstaller due to issues with locating the tcl/tk modules. I did not think those would lead to this issue.

**Is this the problem of tkinter?
or pyhon 3, I have no idea because i am new to python

Any help would be appreciated.

you can the API key from openweathermap.org but it won't be needed as program is to be executed only for GUI.**

Comment: I believe this is an issue with pyinstaller on Mac; although the documentation says it works on Mac as well as Windows, I have never gotten it to work on Mac but only on Windows.  My issue is the exact same as yours:  a blank black window for the GUI.

Comment: This may be because it makes .exe files, instead of .app files.  If you want your application to work correctly on Mac, I would highly recommend py2app, which does make .app files and is also free to download.  It has worked perfectly for me on Mac every time.

Comment: Here is the documentation: https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: If you only have the problem when trying to run your bundled executable file, and not when running the original Python script, it is almost definitely a problem with PyInstaller.  Could it be the issue discussed here?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51847801/pyinstaller-app-not-opening-on-mac